# Vuetify.js Datepicker set allowed dates for each datepicker in array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have this **toAllowedDates** method that allows the datepicker to only select a date range which has an interval of only 1 day. I've been trying to solve this for almost half a day with little to no luck. It will help if I can get any opinions. Maybe my way of doing it is wrong in the first place.

```
methods: {
  toAllowedDates(val) {
    // I need the index here but if I pass the index in the loop it will not pass the value
    const today = this.$moment(this.schedules[index].dayFrom, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    const maxAllowedDate = today.clone().add(1, "days")
    const currentDate = this.$moment(val)
    return !today.isAfter(currentDate) && !currentDate.isAfter(maxAllowedDate)
    }
  }
```

by default this will pass the vals(day1~day30)

```
<template v-for="(schedule, index) in schedules">
  <sw-calendar-range 
   :value="[schedule.workdayDateFrom, schedule.workdayDateTo]"
   :to-allowed-dates="toAllowedDates"
   @input="updateWorkdaySchedule(['workdayDateFrom', 'workdayDateTo'], index, $event)">
  </sw-calendar-range>
</template>
```

what I tried to be able to pass the index to the **toAllowedDates** method but no luck

```
<template v-for="(schedule, index) in schedules">
  <sw-calendar-range 
   :value="[schedule.workdayDateFrom, schedule.workdayDateTo]"
   :to-allowed-dates="toAllowedDates(val, index)"
   @input="updateWorkdaySchedule(['workdayDateFrom', 'workdayDateTo'], index, $event)">
  </sw-calendar-range>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a function for each allowed-dates. I hope this helps someone in the future.

in my data I created an empty array for my methods

```
data: () => ({
    ...
    newMethods: []
  }),
```

in my methods

```
setAllowedDatesTo(idx) {
      this.$set(this.allowedDates, 'To' + idx, val => {
        const today = this.$moment(this.formWorks.workdaySchedules[idx].workdayDateFrom, "YYYY-MM-DD")
        const maxAllowedDate = today.clone().add(1, "days")
        const currentDate = this.$moment(val)
        return !today.isAfter(currentDate) && !currentDate.isAfter(maxAllowedDate)
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

prop:

```
    :to-allowed-dates="(val) => toAllowedDates(val, index)"
```

Methods:

```
toAllowedDates(val, index) {
    const today = this.$moment(this.schedules[index].dayFrom, "YYYY-MM-DD")
    const maxAllowedDate = today.clone().add(1, "days")
    const currentDate = this.$moment(val)
    return !today.isAfter(currentDate) && !currentDate.isAfter(maxAllowedDate)
}
```